# Pattern for adding information to a request that was submitted

Tags: forms, interaction-design, design-patterns, inline-edit, required-fields

I'm designing a flow for an approver. It is a relatively complex problem.

Requestors can submit requests which go to an approver to approve.

The approver needs to be able to see the details of the request coming in and in addition they can add some details to the request that the requestor did not have. After this, they can officially "Approve" the request.

Curious if anyone knows of a pattern for mixing editable & non-editable information into one area. For e.g. DocuSign has sign-able fields and information for a contract. Would love some help to brainstorm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

Under each content section (or paragraph) create a conversation for edits.

The requestor submits a section. After this, a timeline conversation begins right below each section. This timeline can be a chat-like feature where every suggestion and change is well documented. I uploaded a quick wireframe to show my idea.

[image: wireframe of idea]

Answer (score 0):

If you decouple the problem to prime factors it's not that difficult.

There are 2 roles:

- Requester
- Approver

In simplify according to **Event Storming** - the 2 basis actions are:

- **Request** by Requester (some CTA, button or alternative)
- **Approved** by Approver (some CTA, button or alternative)

An entity in the database with an additional boolean column **isApproved** (but this can be done in x other ways.

The order in time cannot be random - **Request** - must be before **Approving**

---

In the UI context - the system should reuse the existing components - meet the standards - and look aesthetically.

Additional - where the CTA should be located? there is in chat? in user/admin panel? - there is correlated with Your app usability.